# How to compile assembly with SDL in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, assembly, compilation

I am quite new to assembly and Linux as a whole. I found on gitHub a snake program written in Assembly. But I tried compiling and running it, but have no clue how.

I first thought I could use gcc -o *name* *name.s* and that didnt work. Then i read that i need to compile it using BASH command "make" however... I really dont know how to do that.

Like I said I am completely new to usuing linux and I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain to me how to compile this and get it running.

Here's the link : https://github.com/weierstrass/asnake

Comment: Type `make` in a terminal